# Argument of a complex number sympi

Tags: python, sympy

when I am working with symbolic variables in sympi, I have to compute the argument of a complex number in sympi type, for this Im using arg() but when I try to compute the argument of zero y get NaN. Why does this happen? I need it to give me arg(0)=0, what can I do? thanks.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, please post a [mcve].

Comment: arg(0) = NaN, it doesn't make any sense the argument of 0 is 0, how can I get the argument of a complex number in symbolic variable?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.